# TYPO3 ajax 404 eID not registered

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, typo3

I have TYPO3 7.6.18. I trying to configure ajax requests on front end. I need that my ajax request call specific plugin controller and action as I need. I tried different ajaxDispatchers.

Now I get error 404 eID not registered

I include ajaxDispatcher on local_conf.php

```
$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['eID_include']['Fefiles'] = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility::extPath('fefiles').'Classes/Ajax/EidDispatcher.php';
```

EidDispatcher.php

```
<?

use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ArrayUtility;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\ExtensionManagementUtility;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility;
use \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Utility\EidUtility;/**/

/**
 * Gets the Ajax Call Parameters
 */
$_gp = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_POST();
$_gp = \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Utility\ArrayUtility::arrayMergeRecursiveOverrule(
    $_gp,
    \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::_GET()
);

$ajax = array();
$ajax['arguments']  = $_gp;
$ajax['vendor']     = 'Nng';
$ajax['extensionName']  = 'Nnfesubmit';
$ajax['pluginName']     = 'Pi1';
$ajax['controller']     = 'Eid';
$ajax['action']     = 'processRequest';



/**
 * @var $TSFE \TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController
 */
global $TYPO3_CONF_VARS;

$TSFE = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Controller\TypoScriptFrontendController', $TYPO3_CONF_VARS, 0, 0);
$GLOBALS['TSFE'] = $TSFE;

\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Utility\EidUtility::initLanguage();
\TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\Utility\EidUtility::initTCA();
// Get FE User Information
$TSFE->initFEuser();
$TSFE->initUserGroups();
// Important: no Cache for Ajax stuff
$TSFE->set_no_cache();

$TSFE->checkAlternativeIdMethods();
$TSFE->determineId();
$TSFE->initTemplate();
$TSFE->getConfigArray();
\TYPO3\CMS\Core\Core\Bootstrap::getInstance();

$TSFE->cObj = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer');
$TSFE->settingLanguage();
$TSFE->settingLocale();

/**
 * Initialize Backend-User (if logged in)
 */
$GLOBALS['BE_USER'] = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Core\Authentication\BackendUserAuthentication');
$GLOBALS['BE_USER']->start();

/**
 * Initialize Database
 */
$TSFE->connectToDB();

/**
 * @var $objectManager \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager
 */
$objectManager = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Object\ObjectManager');

/**
 * Initialize Extbase bootstap
 */
$bootstrapConf['extensionName'] = $ajax['extensionName'];
$bootstrapConf['pluginName']    = $ajax['pluginName'];

$bootstrap = new \TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Core\Bootstrap();
$bootstrap->initialize($bootstrapConf);
$bootstrap->cObj = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('TYPO3\CMS\Frontend\ContentObject\ContentObjectRenderer');

/**
 * Build the request
 */
$request = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Request');

$request->setControllerVendorName($ajax['vendor']);
$request->setcontrollerExtensionName($ajax['extensionName']);
$request->setPluginName($ajax['pluginName']);
$request->setControllerName($ajax['controller']);
$request->setControllerActionName($ajax['action']);
$request->setArguments($ajax['arguments']);


//$ajaxDispatcher = \TYPO3\CMS\Core\Utility\GeneralUtility::makeInstance('Nng\Nnsubscribe\Controller\EidController');
//echo $ajaxDispatcher->processRequestAction();

$response = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\ResponseInterface');
$dispatcher = $objectManager->get('TYPO3\CMS\Extbase\Mvc\Dispatcher');
$dispatcher->dispatch($request, $response);

echo $response->getContent();




?>
```

my js request:

```
var request = {
            id: 1,
            mvc: {
                vendor:            'Istar',
                extensionName:     'Fefiles',
                pluginName:        'Piphoto',
                controller:        'Photo',
                action:            'test'
            },

        };

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url: "index.php",
            data: {
                eID:       'Fefiles',
                request:   request
            },
            success: function(msg){
                console.log(msg);
            }
        });
```

I think it can be useful not only for me, but for other users too. People, help me please fix this problem and understand what is this eID. Great thank for advice!

Answer (score 0):

$GLOBALS['TYPO3_CONF_VARS']['FE']['eID_include']['ajaxDispatcher']

['ajaxDispatcher']  here must be the same as you send in eID)

Answer (score 0):

Please consider using a page type instead of eID when using Extbase. See this blog post: http://insight.helhum.io/post/104880845705/dont-use-eid-ajax-dispatchers-for-your-extbase

Answer (score -1):

Your eID must be set in url not in post data.
The Request should be:

var request = {
            id: 1,
            mvc: {
                vendor:            'Istar',
                extensionName:     'Fefiles',
                pluginName:        'Piphoto',
                controller:        'Photo',
                action:            'test'
            },

```
    };

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php?eID=Fefiles",
        data: {
            request:   request
        },
        success: function(msg){
            console.log(msg);
        }
    });
```